# Monitor dimming inconsistently

Tags: gnome, 14.10, screen

Occasionally the screen dims and also turn back normal on it's own even though I have disabled "dim screen when inactive" and have set "Blank screen" to "never" in power options. Moreover, the system really isn't 'inactive' while the screen is being dimmed and the monitor comes back almost immediately or when mouse or keyboard is used.

What could be the possible reason of this problem? What can be done to probe on this further?